# How to run a command against all the files of particular types on a filesystem?

Tags: shell, files, find, data-recovery, archive

I've just recovered tons of files (distributed in a complex directory structure, having very long names, using Unicode symbols, spaces etc in names) from a damaged hard drive. Now I'd like to verify all files which contain verification information (like zip archives (including LibreOffice and other XML-in-ZIP kind documents), 7z and rar archives, self-extracting exe arcives etc.)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

To locate files by name:

```
find /mount/point -type f \( \
    \( -name '*.zip' -o -name '*.o[dt][bcfghipst]' \) -exec unzip -t {} \; \
    -o -name '*.7z' -exec 7z t {} \; \
    …   \)

find /mount/point -type f \( -name '*.7z' -o -name '*.o[dt][bcfghipst]' \) -exec unzip -t {} \;
```

To locate files by type:

```
find /mount/point -type f -exec sh -c '
  case "$(file --mime-type -b - <"$0")" in
    application/zip) unzip -t "$0";;
    application/x-7z-compressed) 7z t "$0";;
    application/rar) unrar t "$0";;
    …
  esac
' {} \;
```